# how to create a class so that the vector works std::vector<MyClass<int>> v{ 1,2,3 };

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

I need a class so that the instruction works

```
int main() {
// create a vector with values 10,2,3
std::vector<MyClass<int>> v{ 10,2,3 };
//print values
for (const auto& m : v) std::cout << m.value() << ",";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write a `template` class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
private:
  T val;
public:
  MyClass(T a) : val{std::move(a)} {}
  T value() const { return val; }
};
```

Note that if you mark the constructor as `explicit`:

```
  explicit MyClass(T a) : val{std::move(a)} {}
```

Then you will have to explicitly construct the values in the vector initializer list:

```
std::vector<MyClass<int>> v{ MyClass<int>{10}, MyClass<int>{2}, MyClass<int>{3} };
```

Comment: Note that with the `explicit` you [can still `emplace`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27739e3ab7cc8943)